# C# await lambda function

Tags: c#, lambda, async-await

I'll start off by publishing the code that is troubled:

```
    public async Task main()
    {
       Task t = func();
       await t;
       list.ItemsSource = jlist; //jlist previously defined
    }


    public async Task func()
    {
        TwitterService service = new TwitterService(_consumerKey, _consumerSecret);
        service.AuthenticateWith(_accessToken, _accessTokenSecret);


        TwitterGeoLocationSearch g = new TwitterGeoLocationSearch(40.758367, -73.982706, 25, 0);


        SearchOptions s = new SearchOptions();
        s.Geocode = g;
        s.Q = "";
        s.Count = 1;
        service.Search(s, (statuses, response) => get_tweets(statuses, response));

    void get_tweets(TwitterSearchResult statuses, TwitterResponse response)
    {
        //unimportant code
        jlist.Add(info);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("done with get_tweets, jlist created");

    }
```

I am having issues with the get_tweets(..) function running (on what I believe a different thread) and the Task t is not awaited like I have in the main function. Basically, my issue is that the list.Itemsource = jlist is ran before the get_tweets function is finished.  Does anyone have a solution or the right direction to point me in?

Comment: Are you not getting a warning to say that your `func()` async method doesn't contain any `await` statements?

Comment: I don't think you've copied enough code for us to see what the problem is; func(), for example, has no await statements and so should run synchronously.

Comment: @antlersoft No, there's enough code.  The problem is he's using a method that takes a callback, so it's asynchronous but it uses a non-task async model.  That's the underlying problem.

Answer (score 2):

First, create a [TAP wrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178.aspx#EAP) for `TwitterService.Search`, using `TaskCompletionSource`. So something like:

```
public static Task<Tuple<TwitterSearchResult, TwitterResponse>> SearchAsync(this TwitterService service, SearchOptions options)
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Tuple<TwitterSearchResult, TwitterResponse>>();
  service.Search(options, (status, response) => tcs.SetResult(Tuple.Create(status, response)));
  return tcs.Task;
}
```

Then you can consume it using `await`:

```
SearchOptions s = new SearchOptions();
s.Geocode = g;
s.Q = "";
s.Count = 1;
var result = await service.SearchAsync(s);
get_tweets(result.Item1, result.Item2);
```